Choosing pairs of subsets having exactly $n$ elements common
There's a set $A$ having $22$ elements. A subset $P$ is chosen from $A$ randomly. Similarly, a subset $Q$ is also chosen. What is the total number of possible pairs of subsets P and Q such that they share exactly $5$ elements in common?
My approach
First we select common elements which gives $\binom{22}{5}$. Now we've to fill up $P$ and $Q$ such that no two elements are same. For this we've $\binom{17}{2} × 2$ selections. So total selections: $$\binom{22}{5} \binom{17}{2} × 2$$
This is NOT the correct answer as there is some over counting. How do I eliminate the extra pairs? Or is there any other approach to this problem?

Can you elaborate on "Now we've to fill up $P$ and $Q$ such that no two elements are same. For this we've $\binom{17}{2} × 2$ selections."?   Perhaps consider when $A$ has 7 elements, and we want $P, Q$ to have 5 elements in common. $\quad$ Also, what do you think is the correct answer? I believe that you've significantly undercounted, so I'm wondering why you think that there's some overcounting.

@CalvinLin ah! I get what you're saying. After filling up 5 common elements, it's not necessary that all of set A is to used for filling P and Q.

Your first step works but then, we can split the remaining 17 elements into 3 categories, the elements in $P$, the elements in $Q$, and the elements in neither. Hence, each element has 3 choices so we get there are $\begin{pmatrix} 22\\ 5 \end{pmatrix} 3^{17}$ choices of $P$ and $Q$.

Your first step is correct. For the second part (ie. the remaining elements), just think how many ways they can be "assigned to different cases".

The number of ways to find $5$ elements is ${22\choose5}$. for The remaining $22-5=17$ elements, each of them can be decided to which case in $3$ ways, to be specific it can be (in $P$ and not in $Q$) or (in $Q$ and not in $P$) or (neither in $P$ nor $Q$), so there are $3^{17}$ ways to put each element into $3$ cases. Hence the final answer is ${22\choose5}\cdot 3^{17}$.
